# jquery bug with this function

Tags: jquery

i'm not able to get the id of the div field where the radio boxes changed. If I remove the table coding from the html, this coding would work. Any ideas?

Example HTML:

```
        $PLAN_REPORT_DATE_HTML .= qq|<div id="planreportdate-$TECH_ID---$METRIC_ID---$SIZE_ID">

        <table><tr><td>
        ${FOUNDRY_NAME}_${TECHFLAVOUR}-$SIZE_VALUE<br><br>

        <input type="radio" name="radiovalue-$count" value="Latest" > Latest <br> 
        <input type="radio" name="radiovalue-$count" value="MajorUpdates" > Major Updates <br>
        <input type="radio" name="radiovalue-$count" value="All" >All<br>
        </td></tr><tr><td>
        <select name="plan-$count" multiple id="plan-$TECH_ID---$METRIC_ID---$SIZE_ID" size="5">|;
```

Jquery Coding

```
     $("div[id^='planreportdate-'] input[name^='radiovalue-']").change(function(event) {

            var id_value = $(this).parent().attr('id');
            var value= $("div[id="+ id_value + "] input[name^='radiovalue-']:checked").val();

            var selectboxid = id_value.replace(/^planreportdate-/g,"");

            if (value == "All")
            {
                // THIS CODING SELECTS ALL THE SELECT OPTIONS

                $("#plan-" + selectboxid).each(function() {
                    $("#plan-" + selectboxid + " option").attr("selected","selected");
                });
            }
```

Comment: It would be much easier to help if you posted the rendered HTML from the browser rather than all this inline code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would add a class to the parent and use `.parents()` like this:

```
    $PLAN_REPORT_DATE_HTML .= qq|<div id="planreportdate-$TECH_ID---$METRIC_ID---$SIZE_ID" class="parentOfRadios">

    <table><tr><td>
    ${FOUNDRY_NAME}_${TECHFLAVOUR}-$SIZE_VALUE<br><br>

    <input type="radio" name="radiovalue-$count" value="Latest" > Latest <br> 
    <input type="radio" name="radiovalue-$count" value="MajorUpdates" > Major Updates <br>
    <input type="radio" name="radiovalue-$count" value="All" >All<br>

    //.parents() to select
    var id_value = $(this).parents('.parentOfRadios').first().attr('id');
```

See the difference between [.parents()](http://api.jquery.com/parents/) and [.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) jQuery function to find the DIV that is closest to the radio button in the DOM. Using `.parent()` won't work, because the immediate parent element of the radio button is the `<td>` element, not the `<div>` element that you're interested in. Like so:

```
var id_value = \$(this).closest('div').attr('id');
```